# Python3 - Tkinter - Widget creation with a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, tkinter

Im trying to create widgets dynamically onto the root window of `tkinter` with a `json` file as a widget config. I simplified the code so you can also test things out. (Im using `grid()` in my main code but its not necessary here)

The json file contains an `items` list with each widget in a seperate dict, it can look for example like this.

```
new_dict = {
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "frame",
            "id": "f1"
        },
        {
            "type": "button",
            "id": "b1",
            "text": "Button1"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal here to create a widget, stored in the `value` of the `id` field, so i can later on change widgets states or other things via `.config()`

*( Example: `f1 = Frame(root)` )*

For this example my code looks like this:

( **Note:** im using `locals()` to create the specific variables, if there is a better way, please let me know )

```
# Example: Change Frame Color to Blue
def change_background(frame_id):
    locals()[frame_id].config(bg=blue)

# Root Window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

# Widget Creation
for item in new_dict["items"]:
    if item["type"] == "frame":
        frame_id = item["id"]
        locals()[item["id"]] = Frame(root, width=200, height=200, bg="green")
        locals()[item["id"]].pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
    elif item["type"] == "button":
        locals()[item["id"]] = Button(root, text=item["text"], command=lambda: change_background(frame_id))
        locals()[item["id"]].place(x=50, y=50, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Now my problem here is that i cant give the `frame id` into the `change_background` function. If i do that im getting following Error:

```
KeyError: 'f1'
```

I dont quite understand the problem here, because `pack()`, `place()` and `grid()` works fine with each widget.

Comment: As what the name `locals` means, it stores only local variables.  So `locals()` inside the function just contains local variables defined inside the function. It is not recommended to use `locals()` like this. Just use a normal dictionary instead.

Comment: Ah i get it, `globals()` would work in this case. Can you explain what in this case you mean with `Just use a normal dictionary instead.`?

Comment: That is basically replace all `locals()` by, for example, `widgets` and `widgets` should be a dictionary and has been initialized like `widgets = {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what the name `locals` means, it stores only *local* variables. So `locals()` inside the function just contains local variables defined inside the function.

It is not recommended to use `locals()` like this. Just use a normal dictionary instead:

```py
...
# Example: Change Frame Color to Blue
def change_background(frame_id):
    widgets[frame_id].config(bg="blue")

# Root Window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

# Widget Creation
# use a normal dictionary instead of locals()
widgets = {}
for item in new_dict["items"]:
    if item["type"] == "frame":
        frame_id = item["id"]
        widgets[item["id"]] = Frame(root, width=200, height=200, bg="green")
        widgets[item["id"]].pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
    elif item["type"] == "button":
        widgets[item["id"]] = Button(root, text=item["text"], command=lambda: change_background(frame_id))
        widgets[item["id"]].place(x=50, y=50, anchor=CENTER)
...
```