# Python Tk creating buttons named after dictionaries in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Code:

```
Mods = {"links_too":[module_1,module_2,module_3,module_4,module_5,module_6],"Buttons":[],"previous":Mods}
module_1 = {"links_too":[],"Buttons":[],"previous":Mods}

def create_menu_buttons():
    global Mods
    for x in Mods["links_too"]:
        x = ttk.Button(window,text=x,command=nav_load_menu(x))
```

the goal of the code is to create a button for each dictionary in the `"links_too"` section. to do this all the buttons need names so i am naming then by the name of the dictionary. i know this will cause issues as it will have the same name as the dictionary itself but i do not know of another way to do this.
Is there a way to do this in the for loop where the buttons will have different names.

Comment: Change `command=nav_load_menu(x)` => `command=lambda x=x:nav_load_menu(x)`

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two ways that i know that make this possible.

The first one is pretty simple but **not recommended**. Its make use of `globals()` where you can create variables out of a dictionary.

Here is an example:

```
# I've edited the dict a bit to make it runable
Mods = {"links_too":["module_1"],"Buttons":[],"previous":"Mods"}

window = ttk.Tk()

for x in Mods["links_too"]:
    globals()[x + "_button"] = ttk.Button(window,text=x).place(x=0, y=0) #,command=lambda x=x:nav_load_menu(x))

window.mainloop()
print(globals())
```

This will create a global variable `module_1_button` where the actual button is stored.

The second one is by using the value of a dict key as a variable like so. It will do the same thing in a better way.

```
# A recommended way
window = ttk.Tk()

buttons = {
    "button1": {
        "id": "module_1_button"
    }
}

for button in buttons:
    buttons[button]["id"] == ttk.Button(window,text=buttons[button]["id"]).place(x=0, y=0)


window.mainloop()
```

**Note:** I asked a pretty similar question, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74629883/python3-tkinter-widget-creation-with-a-dict/74644123#74644123)